# multifriend selector in php

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to make a Facebook application that utilises the multi-friend-selector to let someone answer a question. (eg: why do you think is the most awesome? you get multi friend selector below, choose someone and click post to his wall).

I've the post to wall part working fine using PHP. Right now though the friend to be asked a question is picked randomly.

Now the question. Is there a way to use PHP to render a multi-friend-selector or do i HAVE to go back and do this whole thing using Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

The multi-friend-selector is under Facebook's control and you cannot use for anything other than sending invitations. So unfortunately you'd have to use your own. Fortunately though, someone else already had this problem and wrote one for you: [Facebook – Friends selection custom component](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/12/24/facebook-friends-selection-custom-component/). Note that it does use some JavaScript.